# Python alternative of the Matlab symvar function

Tags: python, matlab, parsing

Matlab has a function called symvar, that takes a string expression, usually containing valid matlab instructions, and identifies variables. These can then be handled/replaced in order to evaluate the expression.

For example:

```
symvar('cos(pi*x - beta1)')
```

returns

```
{'beta1';'x'}
```

Is there a similar functionality in Python?

Here is an example of how I would use this:
say I have a DataFrame DF (in this case I am referring to the pandas module, but I guess this also applies to numpy recordarray), containing a set of variables, eg A,B,C. I want my user to be able to add an additional column by specifying something like

add_field(DF,"D=log(A)+C*3")

Internally, the function would recognize A, C and D as variables, extract A and D from the dataframe, perform the calculation (using eval or similar), and then add D as new column to the dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: The answer is "yes."  Since that's not very useful, you might want to edit your question to ask what you **really** need to know.  For instance, how to do this.  Or how to make use of it.  Or something other than an existence check.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the list of identifiers from a Python expression is to use the `ast` module:

```
import ast
class IdentifierExtractor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids = set()
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        self.ids.add(node.id)
extractor = IdentifierExtractor()
extractor.visit(ast.parse("cos(pi*x - beta1)"))
print extractor.ids
```

prints

```
set(['x', 'cos', 'pi', 'beta1'])
```

You could also exclude the names defined in the `math` module (or any other namespace):

```
print extractor.ids - set(vars(math))
```

prints

```
set(['beta1', 'x'])
```

(Note that I still don't have any clue what all this might be useful for...)

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would try to convert the user expression as Python source code and then call `eval` on it. `eval` will take care of variable substitutions. For simple use-cases, nothing needs to be done to "convert" the user expression to Python source code.

```
expression = "cos(pi*A + B)" # (user input)
bulitin_vars = {
    "pi": math.pi,
    "e": math.e,
    "cos": numpy.cos,
}
data_vars = {col_name]: df[col_name] for col_name] in df.columns}
all_vars = {**builtin_vars, **data_vars}
result = eval(expression, all_vars)
```

This is a nice design because the user has all of Python available for use in their expression (can use lists, dicts, etc.). If you hand-code a simple expression language, it will likely be less complete, especially with respect to error-handling. Just make sure you catch errors in the `eval` and show them to the user somehow.